# React not re-rendering / adding new element to DOM after setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

The addProject function of my code is updating state correctly but the new project is not added to the DOM afterwards. WHY?

What I tried so far:

1. forceUpdate()
2. Made a deep copy of the array
3. Changed the key for the map to be the project title

```
import React from 'react'

const productBacklog = [
    { id: 1, text: 'FrontEnd'},
    { id: 2, text: 'Finished page - for Cluster'}
];

const parkingLot = [
    { id: 1, text: 'Home page: Google Log In/Github API ---Update: Have Google Cloud account for this'},
    { id: 2, text: 'Screenshots of steps needed to setup test class w/annotation & imports' },
];

const projects = [
    { id: 1, title: 'Parking Lot', children: parkingLot },
    { id: 2, title: 'Product Backlog', children: productBacklog }
];

export default class App extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            projects: projects,
        }
    }

    addProject = () => {
        const newProject = {
            id: Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000),
            title: 'newProject',
            children: [],
        }
        const projects = [...this.state.projects];
        projects.push(newProject);
        this.setState({projects: [...projects]}, () => {
            console.log(this.state.projects)         // SHOWS THAT STATE IS UPDATED CORRECTLY
        })
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div className='App'>
                <input type='button' value='Add project' onClick={this.addProject}/>
                <div className='projects'>
                    {projects.map((project, projectId) =>
                        <div className='Project' key={projectId}>
                            Project-Title: { project.title}
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Map over `this.state.projects` in your JSX, not just `projects`.

Comment: @PéterLeéh Please add your comment as an answer!

Comment: @JoelPeltonen It's almost a typo, so I think it's unnecessary to post this as an answer.

Comment: @PéterLeéh I think each Q deserves an A and you gave this one. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, you need to map over `this.state.projects`. You should carefully name things.. this happened only because you had a global variable called `projects` (which is synced with the component's state, bad idea in my opinion), otherwise it would've been an obvious error.  Also I think functional components are a little bit nicer:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const productBacklog = [
    { id: 1, text: 'FrontEnd'},
    { id: 2, text: 'Finished page - for Cluster'}
];

const parkingLot = [
    { id: 1, text: 'Home page: Google Log In/Github API ---Update: Have Google Cloud account for this'},
    { id: 2, text: 'Screenshots of steps needed to setup test class w/annotation & imports' },
];

const projects = [
    { id: 1, title: 'Parking Lot', children: parkingLot },
    { id: 2, title: 'Product Backlog', children: productBacklog }
];

export default function App() {

    const [state, setState] = useState({projects: projects})

    const addProject = () => {
        const newProject = {
            id: Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000),
            title: 'newProject',
            children: [],
        }
        setState({projects: [...state.projects, newProject]})
    }

    return (
        <div className='App'>
            <input type='button' value='Add project' onClick={addProject}/>
            <div className='projects'>
                {state.projects.map((project, projectId) =>
                    <div className='Project' key={projectId}>
                        Project-Title: { project.title}
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment from Péter Leéh solved the problem: Map over this.state.projects instead of just projects. Thx!